# Solr query string not working for full text searches

Tags: solr, web-crawler

I'm following [this](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/solr-tutorial.html) tutorial on how to perform indexing on sample documents using Solr. The default collection is "gettingstarted" as shown. Now I'm trying to query it. There are 52 entries as shown:

[image]

However, when I replace the `q` argument with say `electronics`, it should return 14 results. However, I get nothing.

When I replace the query string `q` with `cat:electronics`, then I actually get the 14 results. But why is this the case? isn't `q=word` supposed to search for `word` wherever it appears?

Comment: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/solr-tutorial.html#create-a-catchall-copy-field

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. Your assumption that:

> isn't q=word supposed to search for word wherever it appears?

is wrong. If you're using `word` as your only query, and nothing more - you're searching for `word` in [the *default search field*](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/other-schema-elements.html#OtherSchemaElements-DefaultSearchField_QueryOperator). It does not search all available fields in all available documents.

Also be aware that the default query parser assumes that your query is in the [Lucene Query Syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html). To handle more "natural" querying, you can [use the edismax query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-extended-dismax-query-parser.html). This query parser supports the `qf` parameter that tells Solr which fields to search, instead of having to use the `cat:electronics` syntax. Your example would then be `q=electronics&qf=cat`.

In the example documents you've given, `qf=series_t author name cat` is probably a decent value to search all these fields for the given query. You can also append `^<weight>` to a field name to give hits in the different fields different weights. `qf=name^10 cat` would give a hit in `name` ten times the weight of a hit in the `cat` field.

Comment: Interesting. But it says [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/solr-tutorial.html#search-for-a-single-term) that `q=word]` is used for a single term search. This search isn't working correctly in my case. In the example I just linked, there are 4 cases of "foundation". However, I find none when I run it on my machine.

Comment: Sure. But that search is made against the default search field. Having the default search field in schema.xml has been deprecated, and as far as I can tell, have been removed in 7.5 (since you're linking to that documentation I assume that's the version you're playing around with). Add the field name in `df` or use `qf` and `defType=edismax`. My guess is that the default field you want to search is `_text_`, as this is usually used as a "catch all" field which most content is copied to (but it's only searching that field - but that field usually receives a copy of all content in the examples).